# Angular 6 routerlink in child module and router-outlet in parent (app.component)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular6

I'm using the RouterModule and have a problem with the routerLinks.

The routerLinks doesn't work (the anchor isn't clickable) because they are in a child module and I don't know how to fix this problem.

Hierarchy:

App.Module (router-outlet) -> Elements Module -> Navi Module (routerLinks)

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ElementsModule } from './elements/elements.module';

import { LandingComponent } from './pages/landing.component';
import { GenreComponent } from './pages/genre.component';
import { SinglePostComponent } from './pages/singlepost.component';
import { ListComponent } from './pages/list.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { DataService } from './data.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ElementsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {path: "", component: LandingComponent},
            {path: "post/:id", component: SinglePostComponent},
            {path: "lists", component: ListComponent}
        ], {
            useHash: true,
        })
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LandingComponent,
        GenreComponent,
        SinglePostComponent,
        ListComponent
    ],
    providers: [DataService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

navi.componentent.html

```
<a routerLink="/movies">Movies</a>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Post a complete minimal example, as a stackblitz, reproducing the problem. Note that there is no way for your lists route to ever be activated, since the genre route would be activates even for `/lists`.

Comment: The anchor isn't clickable.

Comment: `routerLinks` -> `routerLink` , is it a mistake?

Comment: No, just a typo in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project I have an module specified for handling routes and that my other modules can import:

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

This is imported by my other modules like:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been looking for a solution for hours.